# How to find previous of each unique value in a column based upon datetime column values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `pandas dataframe` with sorting on `column 'DT'` like this:

```
 S             DT             
100    2000-12-12 05:00:00
100    2000-12-12 05:00:50     
89     2000-12-12 05:01:20     
89     2000-12-12 05:02:00     
89     2000-12-12 05:02:35     
98     2000-12-12 05:03:15     
98     2000-12-12 05:03:50     
98     2000-12-12 05:04:28     
98     2000-12-12 05:05:05     
112    2000-12-12 05:05:47
112    2000-12-12 05:06:15
112    2000-12-12 05:07:00
```

How can I find the previous of any given value in `column 'S'` from this data?

Like for S = 112, its previous should give 98, for 98 it should give prev = 89 and so on. I would like to store the previous values for any given 'S' in a separate variable which I can later access in my code.
Any help will be deeply appreciated as I am new to the world of coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), replace all rows without last of consecutive groups by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to missing values and last forward filling mising values.

Solution also working if multiple groups with same values, like changed `89` to `112`.

```
df['prev'] = df['S'].shift().where(df['S'].ne(df['S'].shift())).ffill()
print (df)
      S                   DT   prev
0   100  2000-12-12 05:00:00    NaN
1   100  2000-12-12 05:00:50    NaN
2    89  2000-12-12 05:01:20  100.0
3    89  2000-12-12 05:02:00  100.0
4    89  2000-12-12 05:02:35  100.0
5    98  2000-12-12 05:03:15   89.0
6    98  2000-12-12 05:03:50   89.0
7    98  2000-12-12 05:04:28   89.0
8    98  2000-12-12 05:05:05   89.0
9   112  2000-12-12 05:05:47   98.0
10  112  2000-12-12 05:06:15   98.0
11  112  2000-12-12 05:07:00   98.0
```

If need only previous values in new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.assign(prev=df['S'].shift()).loc[df['S'].ne(df['S'].shift()), ['S','prev']]
print (df1)
     S   prev
0  100    NaN
2   89  100.0
5   98   89.0
9  112   98.0
```

Comment: Are you shifting and filling in the wrong direction maybe..? from OP `"Like for S = 112, its previous should give 98, for 98 it should give prev = 89"`

Comment: @ChrisA - Yop, thank you. Btw, in your answer should be states always unique S values, else `map` wrong assign values

Comment: Yes, from title of question I've made the assumption these values should be unique. I will update my answer to caveat though

Comment: yeh you might be right. Added an alternative just in case :)

Comment: Hi `@jezrael` thanks a lot for the solution. But could you modify the new `DataFrame` solution to give correct results.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values of `S` are unique, you could use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) and create a `dict` with `zip` and slicing. Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) if you need to assign values back into `df`:

```
unique_S = df['S'].unique()
d = dict(zip(unique_S[1:], unique_S))

# print(d)
# {89: 100, 98: 89, 112: 98}

# If you need to assign back into DataFrame, use map
df['prev'] = df['S'].map(d)
```

---

If these are unique "contiguous groups" and not unique values, you could use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to get the previous groups value:

```
groups = df['S'].ne(df['S'].shift()).cumsum()
prev_map = df['S'].groupby(groups).first().shift()

df['prev'] = groups.map(prev_map)
```

[out]

```
      S                   DT   prev
0   100  2000-12-12 05:00:00    NaN
1   100  2000-12-12 05:00:50    NaN
2    89  2000-12-12 05:01:20  100.0
3    89  2000-12-12 05:02:00  100.0
4    89  2000-12-12 05:02:35  100.0
5    98  2000-12-12 05:03:15   89.0
6    98  2000-12-12 05:03:50   89.0
7    98  2000-12-12 05:04:28   89.0
8    98  2000-12-12 05:05:05   89.0
9   112  2000-12-12 05:05:47   98.0
10  112  2000-12-12 05:06:15   98.0
11  112  2000-12-12 05:07:00   98.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `lambda` function:

```
def frst(x):
    if len(x):
        return x[0]

df['prev'] = df.apply(lambda x: frst(df[(df.index<x.name) & (df.S != x.S)].S.tail(1).values), axis = 1)
```

Result:

```
      S                   DT   prev
0   100  2000-12-12 05:00:00    NaN
1   100  2000-12-12 05:00:50    NaN
2    89  2000-12-12 05:01:20  100.0
3    89  2000-12-12 05:02:00  100.0
4    89  2000-12-12 05:02:35  100.0
5    98  2000-12-12 05:03:15   89.0
6    98  2000-12-12 05:03:50   89.0
7    98  2000-12-12 05:04:28   89.0
8    98  2000-12-12 05:05:05   89.0
9   112  2000-12-12 05:05:47   98.0
10  112  2000-12-12 05:06:15   98.0
11  112  2000-12-12 05:07:00   98.0
```

Above method is much slower and not "pythonic" as previous solutions, so consider it only for educational purposes :-)